# special character in squarespace (text block)

Tags: special-characters, squarespace

I wish to use a special character in squarespace 6, using a template with a text block.... **how**?

I tried with

```
&#8594;
```

to include →, but didnt work. I see the code in plain text in the site.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to the squarespace support and they told me that this is not possible. The best way is to literary copy and paste it into the text block.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this ascii character in the code block, use

```
<p>&#8594;</p>
```

→

in the code block and it should solve the problem http://help.squarespace.com/guides/about-the-code-block