# Using German characters (e.g. Umlaut) in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding, squarespace

I am trying to encode German characters in html. I just want to use the special character codes. For the Umlaut, I've tried using both `&Uuml;` and `&#220;` and neither renders properly. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

This is for a Squarespace site, and I am inserting Javascript into their Code Injection page, into the footer.  I am using Javascript to write a German word on the page.  The relevant part of my code looks like the below.  And the problem is that this simply renders "& U uml;ber' (space added by me because the umlaut renders properly on Stack Overflow without it) on the page rather than Uber with an umlaut.  Thanks!

```
 var strings = {
          'About': {
            'de': '&Uuml;ber'
          },
```

Comment: Can you show what you are seeing that seems improper?  What browser are you using?

Answer (score 5):

Try using `&Uuml;` for the German character Ü.

You need to [escape special characters](http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=latin) in HTML, unless...

You address the encoding issue on a document-wide level by adding the following line of code [*at the beginning*](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en#answer) of the `<head>` section:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Then you don't need to escape special characters individually.

---

Further reading:

- [Character encodings for beginners](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding)
- [Declaring character encodings in HTML](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations.en)
- [Declaring character encodings in CSS](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset)

---

UPDATE 1 (Javascript)

- [Convert special characters to HTML in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784586/convert-special-characters-to-html-in-javascript)
- [How to convert characters to HTML entities using plain JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354064/how-to-convert-characters-to-html-entities-using-plain-javascript)

---

UPDATE 2 (Squarespace)

- [HTML Special Characters and Squarespace](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=html%20special%20characters%20squarespace)
- [special character in squarespace (text block)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675788/special-character-in-squarespace-text-block)
- If you are a Squarespace customer, they provide 24/7 customer support. [Contact them directly](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).

Comment: I am using &Uuml;  but it doesn't render as an Umlaut.  Specifically, I want to use this within Javascript to change text on the page.  Is that any different?  Thanks!

Comment: Your question didn't mention Javascript, so I was focused solely on HTML. I have revised my answer with Javascript guidance.

Comment: Did you get it to display properly?

Comment: No.  The whole Squarespace site is being delivered through a Content Delivery Network (Amazon's) so I think that may be interfering with how the characters are displayed.  Any ideas?  Thanks for asking :)

Comment: Hi @Keren, I think I've exhausted all options as a non-customer of Squarespace. However, if you visit their website you'll find they provide 24/7 customer support. Why not contact them directly? I didn't notice any free plans, so I presume you're paying them. Put them to work! ;-)

Comment: Hi @Michael_B.  I did contact them directly---they don't help with this sort of coding stuff.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Such a pesky problem! :-) At this point, I would start looking for other German-language sites built on the Squarespace platform and see how they do it. Doesn't even have to be German. Just any Squarespace site showing special characters.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me.  Use the hex code but eliminate the &# from the beginning and add a /

So, to render the word "Über" within Javascript in Squarespace, use /xdcber